# Combine rows and columns to create a 2x2 table for Fisher's exact test

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-analysis

I need to perform a test of independence on the following crosstab `ct` using python:

[image]

Since there are some values less than 5, I cannot perform the chi-square test of independence. Instead, I need to perform Fisher's exact test.

Since Fisher's exact test implementation on Scipy supports only a 2x2 table, I implemented the following solution:

```
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact

# Combine rows and columns to create a 2x2 table
table_2x2 = np.array([[ct[1][4] + ct[2][4] + ct[1][3] + ct[2][3], ct[3][4] + ct[4][4] + ct[3][3] + ct[3][3]],
                      [ct[1][2] + ct[2][2] + ct[1][1] + ct[2][1], ct[3][2] + ct[4][2] + ct[3][1] + ct[4][1]]])

# Perform Fisher's exact test on the 2x2 table
odds_ratio, p_value = fisher_exact(table_2x2)

# Display the results
print(f'Odds Ratio: {odds_ratio}')
print(f'P-value: {p_value}')
```

Is this a valid solution? if not is there any other suggestion to implement this in Python?

Comment: I'm not sure sure about combining the cells (Cross Validated might be a better forum for that question), but I've suggested a test you can use below. If you'd like, I can suggest another solution that may be easier to understand: we can simulate the null distribution of the chi-squared test by randomly sampling contingency tables with the same marginals as your observed table and computing the test statistic for each. This is also approximate because it's randomized, but it doesn't make asymptotic assumptions. LMK if you'd like me to add that.

Answer (score 1):

> if not is there any other suggestion to implement this in Python?

If you're willing to accept a randomized permutation test, you can create your own test using [`scipy.stats.permutation_test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.permutation_test.html). We'll use the same test statistic as `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`, but the null hypothesis will be analogous to that of Fisher's exact test.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

table = np.asarray([[20, 49, 25, 4], 
                    [35, 54, 43, 12], 
                    [27, 44, 29, 8], 
                    [7, 20, 16, 4]])

# perform chi-squared test as a sanity check
ref = stats.chi2_contingency(table)

def untab(table):
    # convert 2d contingency table to two (paired) samples
    # e.g. you have 20 pairs of (0, 0), 49 pairs of (0, 1)...
    x = []
    y = []
    m, n = table.shape
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            count = table[i, j]
            x += [i]*count
            y += [j]*count
    return np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)

x, y = untab(table)

def statistic(x):
    # Given one of the samples, compute the chi-squared statistic.
    # `permutation_test` will pass in random permutations of `x`,
    # and this will compute the statistic for each. This gives us
    # a sense of the distribution of the statistic under the null
    # hypothesis of no association.
    table = stats.contingency.crosstab(x, y).count
    return stats.chi2_contingency(table).statistic

res = stats.permutation_test((x,), statistic, alternative='greater', 
                             permutation_type='pairings')

print(res.pvalue, ref.pvalue)  # 0.6592 0.6500840391351904
```

For the contingency table shown in the original post, there is little difference in the p-value compared to the chi-squared test. Even though some of the counts in the tables are small, it seems that the null distribution of our randomized permutation test is very similar to the chi-squared distribution with the appropriate number of degrees of freedom:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(res.null_distribution, bins=30, density=True, label='normalized histogram')

# see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html
# for degrees of freedom
df = table.size - sum(table.shape) + table.ndim - 1
dist = stats.chi2(df)
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 300)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), label='chi2')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

For more information about the theory (er, intuition) behind the test, please see the SciPy tutorial on [Resampling and Monte Carlo Methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/resampling.html), especially 2c, [Correlated Sample Permuation Tests](https://nbviewer.org/github/scipy/scipy-cookbook/blob/main/ipython/ResamplingAndMonteCarloMethods/resampling_tutorial_2c.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I have one additional question. Why is the permutation_type='pairings' not independent?

Comment: Suppose that when you measure Q13, the possible outcomes are "A" or "B", and when you measure Q6, the possible outcomes are "1" or "2". Futher suppose you took the following observations: (A, 1), (A, 1), (A, 1), (B, 2), which you might represent as two separate arrays: `x = [A, A, A, B], y = [1, 1, 1, 2]`. `permutation_type='independent'` would result in permutations like `x = [1, A, B, 1]`, `y = [2, A, A, 1]`, which is nonsense in this context. `permutations='pairings'` permutes the order of `x`, which results in different pairings between `x` and `y`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the other answer I had in mind: instead of a permutation test, we can perform a Monte Carlo test, which is a bit simpler conceptually.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table = np.asarray([[20, 49, 25, 4], 
                    [35, 54, 43, 12], 
                    [27, 44, 29, 8], 
                    [7, 20, 16, 4]])

# Get distribution of contingency tables under the null
# hypothesis of no association
rowsums, colsums = stats.contingency.margins(table)
dist = stats.random_table(rowsums.ravel(), colsums.ravel())

# Monte Carlo null distribution: compute statistic for contingency
# tables randomly sampled under the null hypothesis
n = 9999
null_distribution = np.empty(n, dtype=float)
for i in range(n):
    resampled = stats.chi2_contingency(dist.rvs())
    null_distribution[i] = resampled.statistic

# Compared observed statistic against Monte Carlo null distribution
observed = stats.chi2_contingency(table)
count_extreme = (null_distribution >= observed.statistic).sum()
pvalue = (count_extreme + 1)/(n + 1)  # 0.6534

# Plot Monte Carlo null distribution against astymptotic approximation
plt.hist(null_distribution, bins=30, density=True, label='Monte Carlo')
df = table.size - sum(table.shape) + table.ndim - 1
dist = stats.chi2(df)
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 300)
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), label='Asymptotic')
plt.legend()
plt.title("Null Distribution of Chi2 Test")
```

[image]

There is very good agreement between the p-values, and the null distribution of the asymptotic test and Monte Carlo test appear to match.

Assuming you're interested in small p-valuies, more informative is the plot of the survival function probabilities against one another. This will tell you if the asymptotic test is too conservative or not conservative enough (for similar contingency tables) around your threshold for significance:

```py
ecdf = stats.ecdf(null_distribution)
q = ecdf.sf.quantiles[::-1]
prob_mc = ecdf.sf.probabilities[::-1]
prob_asymp = dist.sf(q)
plt.plot(prob_mc, prob_asymp)
plt.xlabel("MC Null Distribution Survival Probability")
plt.ylabel("Asymptotic Null Distribution Survival Probability")
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '--')
plt.xlim(0, 0.1)
plt.ylim(0, 0.1)
```

[image]

They match really closely, so for this contingency table (at least), the asymptotic chi-squared test is pretty safe.